# Request header field resource is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: getstream-io

I have gotten this error before while working with other APIs, and, to my knowledge, it had always been a server-side issue. This occurs when I use stream API from within a Unity player on a Netlify server.

Is there somewhere I need to specify the origin of my website for this to work? The error occurs when I call this URL (censored user info):

https://us-east-api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/feed/MyFeed/MyUser/?&api_key=MyKey

Answer (score 0):

Well...Simply remove the 'resource' header from your request. For whatever reason I thought that was necessary. For anyone whom this may help :)